# How to figure out how many exceptions raised python

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, exception, string-length

I want to find out the number of raised exceptions and use it with if statement. To be more clear: If it raises more than 10 TimeoutException following one after another, print "There is a problem with website". I searched for it but I couldn't find anything. I hope there is a efficent way to do this.

Here is the code:

```
while True:
    try:
        browser.get("url")
        return
    except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
        print "Timeout"
```

What I want to do is: If it raises more than 10 Timeout exceptions, print "There is a problem with website"

Comment: Start a counter outside the loop, then increment it and check it on exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep track of the number of times the exception has been raised in a counter. Try something like:

```
count = 1

while True:
    try:
        browser.get("url")
    except selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:
        count += 1
        if count >= 10:
            print 'There is a problem with website'
            break
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there is a problem with the loop when I add the count like this, I deleted break because when count is greater than 10 it must still continue the process, it only needs to warn me. But that way my loop became not to work which it works before, there must be a problem with the code or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: EDIT the question and explain your problem clearly or ask it as a new question.